# shallow matrix construction in octave C++ api

Tags: c++, matrix, octave, shallow-copy

Is there a way to construct a Matrix in octave's C++ api from a pointer to data + size (ie, not using deep copy)? Possibly an undocumented unsafe way, where the caller has to manage the corresponding memory, or a way to assign the pointer to data?
The only thing I could find was a method in dMatrix.h, but it is private:

```
Matrix (double *d, octave_idx_type r, octave_idx_type c);
```

Same with Array.h, the pointer to data seems private.

Comment: Is there any reason why you must do this? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: For efficiency reason, to avoid data copying. This is usually possible in matrix libraries.